# Mounting as <user>, a loop still assigns root ownership

Tags: linux, mount, fstab, loop-device

I am trying to set up a virtual drive from a file. This file will then be written to a flash device (not relevant). Because creating and manipulating the virtual drive will be in a script, I need to do it in user space, i.e., not as root. The script is for building and creating an image for a flash device; so, running as root will be problematic.

In order to mount the file as a virtual drive, I added the following line to /etc/fstab:

`/home/user/drive.img /home/user/mnt ext4 loop,rw,user,noauto,noexec 0 0`

The problem is that when I mount the virtual drive, root takes ownership of ~/mnt, defeating the purpose of mounting it as a regular user.

I know that other file systems allow you to mount while specifying the uid/gid, but the virtual drive must be ext4 to be compatible with an existing process. I tried udisksctl, but it requires root authentication for loopback.

I am going to try mounting then changing ownership (as root) but never unmount it. I will do a 'sync' then take a snapshot of the virtual drive. I do not like it because it is not clean, but it may work for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The step you haven't mentioned is how you created the ext4 filesystem, which is the source of the problem.  Using `mkfs.ext4 /home/user/drive.img` will create a root inode owned by root, so when you mount it, it will still belong to root.

The solution is to add option `-E root_owner` to make it belong to the user running `mkfs.ext4`, or even `-E root_owner=$uid:$gid` for some explicit numeric user and group id.
(Another solution is to use `debugfs` (package `e2fsprogs` for Fedora) to edit the inode.) This example worked for me:

```bash
uid=$(id -u)
gid=$(id -g)
rm -f /tmp/ext4fs
truncate -s 50M /tmp/ext4fs
if true
then mkfs.ext4 -E root_owner=$uid:$gid /tmp/ext4fs
else mkfs.ext4 /tmp/ext4fs
     debugfs -w -R "set_inode_field . uid $uid" /tmp/ext4fs
     debugfs -w -R "set_inode_field . gid $gid" /tmp/ext4fs
fi
# echo '/tmp/ext4fs /tmp/mymnt ext4 loop,rw,user,noauto,noexec' >>/etc/fstab
mkdir -p /tmp/mymnt
mount /tmp/ext4fs
ls -lRa /tmp/mymnt
touch /tmp/mymnt/afile
ls -l /tmp/mymnt
umount /tmp/ext4fs
```

On mount the `ls` shows the mount point as

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 meuh  users  1024 May 15 21:04 .
```

and allows me to create a file there.

Comment: Thank you. You taught me one more trick: the use of truncate. I was using dd. Should I be worried that this will be a sparse file when I burn it on the flash part?

Comment: Sparseness is an internal optimisation that has no visible externel effects. Remember to [tick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) the answer if it resolves your question so other readers know.

Comment: if you use the `-E` flag you can set the `UID:GID` to other than root as follows `mkfs.ext4 -E root_owner=$UID:$GID /home/user/drive.img`. See `man mkfs.ext4`

Comment: @Kes A much better solution, thanks.